# Clang build error: lib/CheckerDependencyHandlingAnalyzerPlugin.so] Error 1

Tags: clang, llvm

The llvm-project source code is cloned from the newest github repo. 
Build command: `make -j8`. 
Clang build error, error message is:

```
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [tools/clang/lib/Analysis/plugins/CheckerDependencyHandling/CMakeFiles/CheckerDependencyHandlingAnalyzerPlugin.dir/build.make:146: lib/CheckerDependencyHandlingAnalyzerPlugin.so] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file 'lib/CheckerDependencyHandlingAnalyzerPlugin.so'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:34906: tools/clang/lib/Analysis/plugins/CheckerDependencyHandling/CMakeFiles/CheckerDependencyHandlingAnalyzerPlugin.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 67%] Building CXX object tools/clang/lib/Tooling/CMakeFiles/obj.clangTooling.dir/RefactoringCallbacks.cpp.o
[ 67%] Building CXX object tools/clang/lib/Tooling/CMakeFiles/obj.clangTooling.dir/StandaloneExecution.cpp.o
[ 67%] Building CXX object tools/clang/lib/Tooling/CMakeFiles/obj.clangTooling.dir/NodeIntrospection.cpp.o
[ 67%] Building CXX object lib/Transforms/Scalar/CMakeFiles/LLVMScalarOpts.dir/SpeculativeExecution.cpp.o
[ 67%] Building CXX object tools/clang/lib/Tooling/CMakeFiles/obj.clangTooling.dir/Tooling.cpp.o
[ 67%] Building CXX object lib/Transforms/Scalar/CMakeFiles/LLVMScalarOpts.dir/StraightLineStrengthReduce.cpp.o
[ 67%] Building CXX object lib/Transforms/Scalar/CMakeFiles/LLVMScalarOpts.dir/StructurizeCFG.cpp.o
[ 69%] Building CXX object lib/Transforms/Scalar/CMakeFiles/LLVMScalarOpts.dir/TailRecursionElimination.cpp.o
[ 69%] Building CXX object lib/Transforms/Scalar/CMakeFiles/LLVMScalarOpts.dir/WarnMissedTransforms.cpp.o
[ 69%] Linking CXX static library ../../libLLVMScalarOpts.a
[ 69%] Built target obj.clangTooling
[ 69%] Built target LLVMScalarOpts
[ 69%] Built target SampleAnalyzerPlugin
[ 69%] Built target CheckerOptionHandlingAnalyzerPlugin
make: *** [Makefile:171: all] Error 2
```

Other informations:

```
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.18.2
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)
$ uname -a
Linux VM-82-98-centos 5.4.32-1-tlinux4-0001 #1 SMP Tue Jul 21 14:24:37 CST 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ld terminated with signal 9` denotes that your computer ran out of memory (RAM) to compile the project.

The first thing you should try is to reduce the number of threads. So instead of `make -j8`, try `make -j4`.

If you can't compile even with a single thread, then you will probably need to increase the swap size on your computer.